# Model is not a date object on input in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

Using AngularJS I am trying to display a date using an input `type=date`:

```
<input ng-model="campaign.date_start" type="date">
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
Error: error:datefmt
Model is not a date object
```

The date actually comes from a JSON API in the following format:

```
date_start": "2014-11-19"
```

I thought that I could resolve it by using a filter, but this did not work and I get the same error with:

```
 <input ng-model="campaign.date_start | date" type="date">
```

I have also tried converting the string to a date, but again I get the same error:

```
 $scope.campaign.date_start = Date(campaign.date_start);
```

What else can I try?

Comment: If you try to do in console `new Date("2014-11-19");`, it works fine, so problem is somewhere in you data representation.

Comment: Filter can't be used in the ng-model directive because it must be an assignable statement (I.E. you must be able to assign something to it). I haven't tried the directive approaches noted below but I did find an $http interceptor approach that converts date formatted objects to JavaScript dates. This can be found at http://aboutcode.net/2013/07/27/json-date-parsing-angularjs.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to instantiate `campaign.date_start` with `Date` not use it as a function.

It should look something like this (**[small demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3hT3BEqt5fy4rJgchI1z?p=preview)**):

```
$scope.campaign.date_start = new Date(campaign.date_start);
```

Comment: that worked with the word "new" i.e. new Date() thanks

Answer (score 47):

You can use this directive;

```
angular.module('app')
.directive("formatDate", function(){
  return {
   require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue){
        return new Date(modelValue);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

In your html;

```
<input type="date" ng-model="date" format-date>
```

> `$formatters`
>
> `Array.<Function>`
>
> Array of functions to execute, as a pipeline, whenever the model value changes. The functions are called in reverse array order, each passing the value through to the next. The last return value is used as the actual DOM value. Used to format / convert values for display in the control.

Comment: This is the solution I've been looking for, however, I keep getting this error `Error: ngModel:datefmt Model is not a date object` when I try to use it, despite running my directive at a higher priority than the built-in input[date] directive.

Comment: @threed, i bet you have more then one date input in your HTML. If so, you will get error message on every date input that does not have the format-date attribute. This had me fooled for a while.

Comment: Nice solution the problem. But I'm a bit annoyed that this problem exists in the first place. Why doesn't the framework handle this for us? Now we have to parse the serverkode (since we can't get a JavaScript Date object from a JSON-respons) or write a directive to use the date input.

Comment: Also want to mention that is also possible to manipulate the date when reading *from* the date input (when saving data to the server for example): Use $parsers the same way $formatters is used in the above answer.

Comment: I added an if in case your model includes a nullable date `if (modelValue != null) return new Date(modelValue);`

Comment: I also modified this to include using momentJS to insure format and to allow an undefined date to show as mm/dd/yyyy in the input date control... if(modelValue && modelValue.getTime()==0){ return undefined;}else {return moment(modelValue).toDate();}

Comment: This is the best answer I have seen so far.

Answer (score 8):

`cs1707`'s directive is a great, except if the scope value for the date is `null` or `undefined` then it will initialize a date with `1/1/1970`. This is probably not optimal for most people

Below is a modified version on `cs1707`'s directive that will leave a `null`/`undefined` model as is:

```
angular.module('app').directive("formatDate", function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
                if (modelValue){
                    return new Date(modelValue);
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In your html;

```
<input type="date" ng-model="date" format-date>
```

**Another Option**

If you want this to apply to all inputs of type date, then there is no need to add the format-date attribute to each input element. You can use the following directive. (Be careful with this as it might interact with other custom directives in unexpected ways.)

```
angular.module('app').directive("input", function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, modelCtrl) {
            if (attr['type'] === 'date'){
                modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
                    if (modelValue){
                        return new Date(modelValue);
                    }
                    else {
                        return null;
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    };
});
```

In your html;

```
<input type="date" ng-model="date">
```

Answer (score 1):

Another directive solution here:

```
//inside directives.js
.directive('dateField', function () {
    return {
        restrict: ' E',
        scope: {
            ngBind: '=ngModel',
            ngLabel: '@'
        },
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            if ($scope.ngBind != null) {
                var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
                var results = pattern.exec($scope.ngBind);
                var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
                $scope.ngBind = dt;
            };
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/directives/dateField.html'
    }
})
;
```

Add a directive template like this:

```
<!-- app.directives templates/directives/dateField -->
<script id="templates/directives/dateField.html" type="text/ng-template">    
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label ">
        <span class="input-label">{{ngLabel}}</span>
        <input type="date" placeholder="" ng-model="ngBind" />
    </label>
</script>
```

And use it

```
<date-field ng-label="This date..." ng-model="datajson.do.date"></date-field>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Using directive to reset default angular formatters/parsers by `ngModelCtrl.$formatters.length = 0; ngModelCtrl.$parsers.length = 0;`

It works for `input[type="date"]` as well as `input[type="time"]`. Also works well for cordova app

HTML :

```
<input date-input type="time" ng-model="created_time">
```

Angular Directive:

```
app.directive('dateInput', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            //Angular 1.3 insert a formater that force to set model to date object, otherwise throw exception.
            //Reset default angular formatters/parsers
            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.length = 0;
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.length = 0;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way using a directive:

HTML:

```
<input date-input type="time" ng-model="created_time">
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('dateInput', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : {
            ngModel : '='
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            if (scope.ngModel) scope.ngModel = new Date(scope.ngModel);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind, while this will suffice for your initial digest, this will not work should the underlying model be changed or refreshed in another digest cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid from this error using this piece of code which is actually a date format error while we pass our date to some function or API

```
            var options = {
                weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "short",
                day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"
            };
            $scope.campaign.date_start = $scope.campaign.date_start.toLocaleTimeString("en-us", options);
```

where en-us format = Friday‎, ‎Feb‎ ‎1‎, ‎2013‎ ‎06‎:‎00‎ ‎AM hope this will help others to solve issue, i was facing such error and resolved with this.