# Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-05-29T19:06:16.693209Z` to be a date - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on `angular`application with `Django` with `rest-framework`..

The app receives it's info with json from the server.. One of the keys is `created_time`... The value of this field is format according to `iso-8601`, for example `2015-05-29T19:06:16.693209Z`.

In the client I have a field:

```
<input type="time" ng-model="created_time">
```

But when the data is arriving I get this error:

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-05-29T19:06:16.693209Z` to be a date http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2015-05-29T19%3A06%3A16.693209Z
at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
at Array.<anonymous> (angular.js:19807)
at Object.ngModelWatch (angular.js:23289)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14235)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14506)
at done (angular.js:9659)
at completeRequest (angular.js:9849)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:9790)
```

I already tried everything :( the format is exactly as the instructions in the docs of angular...

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This must be happening with angular 1.3+. 1.3+ on wards ng-model for date/time input needs to be a valid date object, string representation of date is no longer allowed. You need to convert string to date object (`$scope.created_time = new Date(dateString)`) and bind it to the ng-model. If you follow the [error link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2015-05-29T19:06:16.693209Z) it has a clear description about the error and how to resolve it.

> All date-related inputs like  require the model to be a Date object. If the model is something else, this error will be thrown. Angular does not set validation errors on the  in this case as those errors are shown to the user, but the erroneous state was caused by incorrect application logic and not by the user.

Comment: Works great but I don't know why it always takes 1 day off, example: '02/02/2017' after the conversion goes '01/02/2017', am I the only one?

Comment: If you don't have $scope (or component) access to the value before it's bound, you can use $parsers and $formatters in a directive like this fiddle demonstrates https://jsfiddle.net/sonicblis/18sn1xat/

Comment: `new Date()` always returns the date according to the user locale, so not an option. If I have 08.33 saved on the server, I want to display 8.33, not whatever GMT offset the user is on.

Comment: @AsafLopez cuz the month starts with 0

Comment: @AsafLopez How will you fix the problem?

Answer (score 35):

If you get your data from a REST Service, you can simply convert your fields to Date.

```
$http.get(url).success(function(data){
     $scope.data = data; // get row data
     $scope.data.mydatefield = new Date($scope.data.mydatefield); // convert filed to date
});
```

Comment: This helped me.Thanks :)

Comment: you should swap the line 2 with 3 to avoid $scope change and running all the workers etc again, like so: 


data.mydatefield = new Date(data.mydatefield);
$scope.data = data;

Answer (score 21):

Create a simple directive that converts the model value:

HTML:

```
<input date-input type="time" ng-model="created_time">
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('dateInput', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : {
            ngModel : '='
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            if (scope.ngModel) scope.ngModel = new Date(scope.ngModel);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: that's work however when model change in runtime throws error

Answer (score 12):

In addition to PSL's answer.
This is how to override angular 1.3+ requirements to be a Date object.

`<input type="date" ng-model="book.date" date-format/>`

```
app.directive('dateFormat', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      //Angular 1.3 insert a formater that force to set model to date object, otherwise throw exception.
      //Reset default angular formatters/parsers
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.length = 0;
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.length = 0;
    }
  };
});
```

It can be used with AngularFire $firebaseObject and works fine with $bindTo 3-way binding. No need to extend $firebaseObject service. It works in Ionic/cordova applications.

[Working example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrey3diq/oypbmvtj/)

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29830783/6437038)

Comment: I recommend using this. No more re-assignment to variables or objects and it's for global usage.

Comment: I had to add "bindToController: true", into directive.

Answer (score 2):

if date get reduced by 1 day, use this code,

```
new Date(moment.utc(value).format('l LT'))
```

Answer (score 1):

In a way similar to [cs1707 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782917/model-is-not-a-date-object-on-input-in-angularjs#answer-27666804), I had to create a directive but doing a part by part string to time conversion. I added it as an answer for those who want fast to copy code.

Add this *directive*:

```
app.directive("formatTime", function(){
   return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue){
        var string=modelValue;
        var date=new Date();
        var time=string.split(':');
        date.setHours(+time[0]);
        date.setMinutes(time[1]);
        date.setSeconds(time[2]);
        return date;
      })
    }
   }
 })
```

And `format-time` to your *HTML* *input* tag:

```
<input type="time" data-ng-model="mytime" format-time>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** Actually this is date format issue, I have resolved this issue by using this piece of code.
**Solution:** Below piece of code will solve this issue:

```
            var options = {
                weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "short",
                day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"
            };
            $scope.created_time = $scope.created_time.toLocaleTimeString("en-us", options);
```

where en-us format = "Friday‎, ‎Feb‎ ‎1‎, ‎2013‎ ‎06‎:‎00‎ ‎AM", hope this will help others to solve issue, i was facing such error and resolved with this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and i directly used the object: I am posting the solution witch i carried out:
1:$userData.dob=new Date(userData.dob);
2:$scope.edit.userdob=userData.dob;
   before 1 i faced above error then i directly created the object and assigned it to the edit scope and the problem got resolved.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to update all dates in Array with Objects

```
var data = [
  { id: "1" , birthday: "2016-01-20T11:24:20.882Z"},
  { id: "2" , birthday: "2016-01-20T11:24:20.882Z"},
  { id: "3" , birthday: "2016-01-20T11:24:20.882Z"},
];

  function convertDataStingToObject (data) {
    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++ ){
      console.log('string: ' + data[i].birthday);
      data[i].birthday = new Date(data[i].birthday);
      console.log('updated: ' + data[i].birthday);
      console.log(typeof(data[i].birthday));
    }

    return data;
  }

convertDataStingToObject(data);
```

Comment: new Date() always returns the date according to the user locale, so not an option. If I have 08.33 am saved on the server, I want to display 8.33 am, not whatever GMT offset the user is on