# AngularJS 1.4.3 [ngModel:datefmt] Expected to be a date

Tags: angularjs, json, date

I'm having some trouble with loading the date inputs through AJAX.
My *PHP server* returns the dates from a *PDO* query as strings in the *JSON* format for instance *2014-01-27*. I have looked at [other forum posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537886/error-ngmodeldatefmt-expected-2015-05-29t190616-693209z-to-be-a-date-a) that tell me to convert the string into a date object:

```
$scope.created_time = new Date(dateString);
```

However, I cannot get it to work on my end. Here is my code for the conversion:

```
results.data.jobCreated = new Date(results.data.jobCreated);
```

I've even checked the data to make sure it is of object type date:

```
alert(results.data.jobCreated instanceof Date);
```

This returns an alert with 'true', but the browser console still gives me the following error:

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2014-01-27` to be a date
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2014-01-27
at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:68)
at Array.<anonymous> (angular.js:21615)
at Object.ngModelWatch (angular.js:25159)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15675)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15951)
at done (angular.js:10364)
at completeRequest (angular.js:10536)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10477)
```

If I display the code directly in the DOM with the double curly brackets, the following shows up:

```
{"jobCreated":"2014-01-28T00:00:00.000Z"}
```

This appears to indicate that the Date object conversion is working, but I'm not sure why Angular is still not accepting my Date object.

Thank you ahead of time for providing any suggestions.

I should also mention that I have a directive that sets the ng-model format to "YYYY-MM-DD" so that I can also validate the date formate on the PHP server:

```
.directive("myModelFilter", ["$filter", function($filter){
   return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) 
      {
        ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
          //convert data from view format to model format

            // Grab the parameters
            var params = scope.$eval(attrs.myModelFilter) ;

            // Filter with the parameters passed
            return $filter(params.filter)(data, params.expr, params.comp);

        });

        ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
            //convert data from model format to view format
            // Grab the parameters
            var params = scope.$eval(attrs.myModelFilter) ;

            // Filter with the parameters passed
            return $filter(params.filter)(data, params.expr, params.comp);
        });
      }
   };
}])
```

This is the HTML for the input:

```
<input name="jobCreated" ng-model="formData.jobCreated" required="required" type="date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" my-model-filter="{filter:'date',expr:'yyyy-MM-dd'}" jquery-date-picker="{dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'}" jquery-mask="{format:'0000-00-00',placeholder:'yyyy-mm-dd'}">
```

Comment: Where are you assigning `results.data.jobCreated` to `datefmt` ?

Comment: See the edited part. The directive might be causing the problem.