# AngularJS ngRequired ngDisabled not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I set a value to an input with `type="date"`, AngularJS won't know if element has value.  Below is my sample code.

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<div name="mainForm" ng-app="appTesting" ng-controller="ctrlTesting" ng-form>
    <input type="date" ng-model="dateField" name="dateField" id="dateField" required />
    <button ng-disabled="mainForm.dateField.$error.required">A disabled button</button>
    <button ng-click="setValue()">Set Value</button>
</div>
<script>
angular.module("appTesting", []).controller("ctrlTesting", function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.setValue = function() {
        $scope.dateField = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        document.getElementById('dateField').value = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    };
});
</script>
```

A disabled button remain disabled after setting a value to an input field.

Is there a way to manually set `$error.required` to `true`?
Or, is there a way to manually trigger `ng-disabled` checking after setting a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to [Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-05-29T19:06:16.693209Z` to be a date - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537886/error-ngmodeldatefmt-expected-2015-05-29t190616-693209z-to-be-a-date-a)

Your ngModel scope variable is not a valid Date object.

Just init your `dateField` variable before `setValue` function.

```
$scope.dateField = new Date();
```

Comment: Yes, this is the valid answer. Thank you sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it shouldn't work for you but this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s15hr7az/) works fine:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div name="mainForm" ng-app="appTesting" ng-controller="ctrlTesting" ng-form>
        <input type="date" ng-model="dateField" name="dateField" id="dateField" required />
        <button ng-disabled="mainForm.dateField.$error.required">A disabled button</button>
        <button ng-click="setValue()">Set Value</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('ctrlTesting', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.setValue = function () {
        $scope.dateField = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        document.getElementById('dateField').value = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Can somebody explain a reason why it doesn't work for me? I am using Chrome as browser.

Comment: This answer only works because of the older version of angularJS. If you add the latest (1.4.7) won't work. In Firebug I get ``TypeError: href is null`` error, but If you open Opera browser console, you'll see the real error, which is ``Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-10-16` to be a date``

Answer (score 0):

insted of using "**myForm.input.$error.required**" attribute,you can use "**myForm.input.$error.date**".

That will serve all your requirement that you want from required attribute.

Comment: Thanks, but ngDisabled didn't work. You can validate with the fiddle from the previous answer.