# Error: ngModel:datefmt Model is not a date object

Tags: c#, angularjs, datepicker, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using angular date picker.But it gives below error.Could you tell me how to sort out it. Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
    <input type="date" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="vm.property.deedDate" 
    is-open="status.opened" datepicker-options="vm.dateOptions" 
date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```

**JS**

```
 vm.property = {};

 vm.init = function () {
                propertyService.getPropertyForEdit({
                    id: propertyId
                }).success(function (result) {
                    vm.property = result.property;
                    vm.property.deedDate = moment(vm.property.deedDate);
                 });
            };

            vm.init();
```

**Returning from Web Api :**

[image]

**Web Api Dto object :**

```
 public class PropertyEditDto : IOutputDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DeedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

**It gives below mentioned console error :**

[image]

Comment: plz check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30537983/3033318)

Comment: @macrog I have set like this `vm.property.deedDate = moment();`.But still it gives same error.Why ?

Comment: I don't know, create a plunker so I may be able to help you

Comment: @macrog When I use like this `vm.property.deedDate = new Date(vm.property.deedDate);` then it is working.Could you tell me why it's not working with the `moment()` ?

Comment: what `moment()` is creating without any .format ?? I'm not sure I never use it like this I usually give some format to moment like this `moment().toISOString();` not really sure what could be your problem.

Comment: @macrog On the doc it says `var now = moment();` is equal to this  `moment(new Date())`.So that means it should create `date object` no ? Where am I wrong ? I have updated my `js` section above too.http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: not sure ... I can't really help you with `moment()`, it looks like moment is formatting this somehow different and angularjs complains about it... so `vm.property.deedDate = new Date(vm.property.deedDate);` is your option or fight with `moment ();` :)

Comment: @macrog Yep,You're correct :).Just for the knowledge.Can You put your answer below ? Then I can close this thread.Thanks a lot for the support :)

Comment: done, you can close the thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please try this:

```
vm.property.deedDate = new Date(vm.property.deedDate);
```

it should works !