# Angular json Date object

Tags: json, angularjs, date

I am having the issue as described here:

[Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-05-29T19:06:16.693209Z` to be a date - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537886/error-ngmodeldatefmt-expected-2015-05-29t190616-693209z-to-be-a-date-a)

There is an obvious solution as said in the answers to just do:

```
myObject.date = new Date(myObject.date);
```

Which in our typescript solution will look even uglier:

```
$http.get(someUrl).then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IMyObject[]>) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        var myObject = response.data[i];
        myObject.someDate = new Date(myObject.someDate.toString());
        myObject.someOtherDate = new Date(myObject.someOtherDate.toString());
        // nullable dates
        if (myObject.anotherDate) {
            myObject.anotherDate = new Date(myObject.anotherDate.toString());
        }
        // .. more dates
    }
});
```

But our project will contain dozens of angular applications, with a lot of date properties. I do not want to manually parse the date string to a javascript date object everytime. Is there a way to automate the parsing of a date string to a date object?

Can I manipulate the returned (C# DateTime) json dates so that angular automatically sees date properties as a Date object? Or should I intercept all $http calls and transform every date? What would be the best way to automate this process?

Pseudo javascript code to visualize what to achieve:

```
function transformDates(obj) {
    if (isArray(obj)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            transformDates(obj[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if(isDateString(obj[prop]) {
                obj[prop] = new Date(obj[prop]);
            } else if(isObject(obj[prop]) {
                transformDates(obj[prop]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found this in the angular changesets, which is intentionally removed:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/efcf98936ad8621050fa232c4caf8c3a26d6140e

Comment: In my projects I'm using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/), which is able to [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) lots of different date-formats. It's method `toDate()` returns a JavaScript Date-object.

Comment: Thank you for your input:) I know I can do that but my issue is that I don't want to parse a date everytime I get a date from the server, but do it from 1 place for every date

Comment: Since you are getting _all_ your data via the `$http`-Service this would be the place to look at. You could either [wrap](https://www.exratione.com/2013/08/angularjs-wrapping-http-for-fun-and-profit/) the `$http`-Service or decorate it. It seems to me that parsing the date would be less expensive ;)

Comment: Why don't you have create a dateFilter for all the dates in angularjs ? So in that case wherever you have a date you just need to filter that date throughout your application with only one date format.

Comment: @VaibhavPachauri because then I have to use that filter everytime I use a date. I want **every** DateTime returned in json to be a Date object

Comment: I agree with @iWörk. JSON data is sent as a string so you'd have to parse it somewhere, seems to me like creating a wrapper is overkill and might even constrain you in some places. You can, however, use other methods to clean the code a bit. You can use a `.forEach` loop to shorten the loop declaration and get rid of the `[i]`'s. If you're using ES6, a `for..of` loop would be even better.

Comment: It's more like why does angular know that a bool in C# returned through json is a boolean in javascript, but a DateTime is not seen as a date but as a string instead