# Momentjs : convert 12 hour to Date object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I'm trying to convert 12 hour string to 24 Date object

`day.from = day.from || moment("6:00", ["h:mm"]).format("HH:mm");`

but I'm getting this error:

```
angular.js:11706 Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `6:00` to be a date
```

any idea please?

Comment: What is day.from ? also you should check these
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2015-05-29T19:06:16.693209Z
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537886/error-ngmodeldatefmt-expected-2015-05-29t190616-693209z-to-be-a-date-a

Comment: `moment` is not a `date` object. angular knows nothing about moment but moment has methods to return date

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pLydsm0q/) is a working fiddle, not throwing any error for me

```
 moment("6:00", ["h:mm"]).format("HH:mm") // working fine
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message makes me think that your `date.from` should be a Date object instead of a String. Note that [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) returns a String.
To get a Date object from moment you can use [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/), so you will have the following code:

```
day.from = day.from || moment("6:00", "h:mm").toDate();
```

**PS.** You don't need an array of formats when parsing your String since you have only one element inside it, that's why I used `"h:mm"` instead of `["h:mm"]`.