# HTML5 input date format with angular scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, date, datetime

I have a HTML 5 `input type="date"`.

```
<input type="date" required ng-model="nm.pick" id="dpicker ">
```

Then in my angular controller, I am assigning value

```
nm.pick = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Now this will give HTML5 default date format of `yyyy-MM-dd`.

But I want date format - `dd/MM/yyyy`

1. I cannot changed `<input type="date">` to `<input type="text"` in my HTML. If I change, dateformat will work fine
2. Then I change input date to input text in controller

   ```
   $("#dpicker").attr("type", "text");
   nm.pick = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
   ```

   which is not working.

Basically I want to change the dateformat to `dd/MM/yyyy` in controller without altering HTML.

What are all the possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Would you like to use moment?

Comment: yes definitely..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way that i know is to use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/). I have used it with angular 1.x.x with no problems. It's pretty easy to use, check this out. You can add the following row:

```
nm.pick = moment(nm.pick).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

This should solve your problem,

Comment: yeah..any brief way to use moment js for my problem?

Comment: `Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `"2017-04-23T00:00:00.000Z"` to be a date` this error i'm getting...   do i have to put new Date(date)?

Comment: @Arun, look through this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537886/error-ngmodeldatefmt-expected-2015-05-29t190616-693209z-to-be-a-date-a It looks like this problem has an answer already

Answer (score 3):

For `type="date"` binding

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.nm = {};
  $scope.nm.pick = new Date($filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="date" required ng-model="nm.pick" id="dpicker ">
</body>
```

Reading other answers, I'd advice the same to go with `moment.js` as it is an expert library when playing around with date/time and different timezone.

Comment: $filter doesnt work in my case, as i have mentioned above. failed to change format through momentjs also

Comment: Which version of angular are you using.. this should work fine on above 1.3

Comment: i am using 1.3.8