# Allowing empty values in HTML5 date input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, date

If I use an HTML5 date input and that field represents a date that maps to a nullable datetime column in the database, how do I get around setting an empty value in the input field?

My application is using AngularJS and my ng-model is mapping to a scope variable with an initial value of null (or an empty string). Here's what the browser's console says:

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2017-09-14T00%3A00%3A00
    at angular.js:88
    at Array.<anonymous> (angular.js:25308)
    at angular.js:29301
    at m.$digest (angular.js:18253)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18531)
    at l (angular.js:12547)
    at s (angular.js:12785)
    at XMLHttpRequest.y.onload (angular.js:12702) undefined
```

The documentation says the value assigned to a date input field must be a Date object. The value I'm trying to pass is not a date because the field doesn't always have a value. I suppose I could provide a default value, such as today's date but I am concerned that users may allow that value to be submitted when that particular field doesn't require a value (e.g. a cancel date for something that isn't canceled yet).

It also seems that depending on which browser you are using you can clear a date the user had previously entered by clicking an "X" button the browser inserts in the field. I tried adding a button to set the value of the field to an empty string but I get the same error.

What I've done in the past as a workaround is to instead use a text input field and use a regular expression to validate the input, but that seems like it shouldn't be necessary and that the date input field should allow empty entries.

Comment: Did you try using an empty string? It works in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/6aYiYDgNc6kLFr1GKBXp?p=preview).

Comment: I guess that does work after all; that error is actually occurring when the date value from my model is being bound. The date format associated with the control is "mm/dd/yyyy" (as per Chrome, just like your example) but the date in question is "2017-09-14T00:00:00". I don't care about the time portion in this case, just the date part. It's almost like it doesn't like the format. How do I get around this? If I can get a fix for this, I'll be sure to fix all the clunky workarounds in the other parts of the application.

Answer (score 0):

It appears my date value is coming back from my REST service as a string, which is not the same as a date.

I found this article that explains a simpler workaround:

[Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-05-29T19:06:16.693209Z` to be a date - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537886/error-ngmodeldatefmt-expected-2015-05-29t190616-693209z-to-be-a-date-a)