# Error thrown while formatting the date

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to format the date shown in a text box. 
 The formating is done using `$filter`.This is the code.

```
$scope.reportsDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
```

This is throwing the below error `[FATAL] [] [-] ["Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/ngModel/datefmt?p0=11%2F29%2F2017Error:`

If that is replaced with `new Date()`, the error wont be there. But then how can I format the date.

Comment: how is `reportsDate` used?

Comment: This is not giving me any error . Can you create a fiddle or something ?

Comment: if you have it in `<input>` with `type="date"`, it will give this [error on AngularJS versions 1.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30537983/8495123). You need to change type to `"text"` for this

Comment: @AlekseySolovey reportsDate is the ng-model for the text box in which the date is displayed

Comment: @AlekseySolovey type is text